# MSVC How does ios_base::Init work?

Tags: visual-c++

The documentation states that:

> The nested class describes an object whose construction ensures that
>   the standard iostreams objects are properly constructed, even before
>   the execution of a constructor for an arbitrary static object.

As seen at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fbyc90zw.aspx

But since static objects have an undefined init ordering how does `ios_base::Init` ensure that it runs before them?

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard that the order of initialization of static variables is undefined, but the order of constructor calls for creation of an object/variable (static or not) is well defined.

Comment: But wouldn't there have to be a static instance of ios_base::Init?

Comment: @paulm Yes. But perhaps that's not what u wanted to hear. Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: In what way? I want to know how ios_base::Init ctor can always run before ios_base ctor?

Answer (score 0):

The `ios_base::Init` class is nested in the `ios_base` class.  So when any `ios_base` instance is constructed, the `ios_base::Init` constructor is run as well.

It doesn't matter which of the possible static instances of an object using `ios_base` exist or what order they run in.  All that matters is that the `ios_base::Init` gets to run and initialize the standard streams first (all other constructor calls to `ios_base::Init` likely do nothing since the work is already done by the first constructor call).

Comment: Does this mean its just a "normal" member of ios_base? E.g class foo { class bar {}; bar mBar; }; ?

Comment: In VS2015 you can see the definition of it in the C++ library's `xiosbase` header.

Comment: It appears to wrap _Init_ctor and _Init_dtor, but this doesn't show what this does or how the Init class gets constructed since its not a member of ios_base